# how to generate a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function called **getCount(df, score, percentage)**, it takes three parameters and it returns a count of ppl base on scores, percentages.

I want to generate a matrix with percentages as index and scores as columns

percentages = [0.1,0.2, 0.3, 0.4] 
scores = [1,2, 3, 4]

and I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
    1  2  3  4  
0.1 45 34 21 10
0.2 14 5  10 5
0.3 34 21 15 9
0.4 54 23 78 21
```

so for instance on the first index 0.1 at first column 1, there are 45 ppl.

Comment: I don't get where the values have come from?

Comment: Check `pivot` or maybe `lookup`

Comment: so value comes from my getCount function,  so getCount(mydf, 1, 0.1) turns 45, agian 45 is just dummy data

Comment: Rather than taking the data out of a DF, then counting it, then putting it back into a df, can you just use `df1=mydf.groupby(['score', 'percentage']).count()` or, as @Wen stated, a pivot if the format isn't right with groupby?

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame()
for percentage in percentages:
    for score in scores:
        mydf.set_value(percentage, score, getCount(data, score, percentage))
```

this might not be the best way to do it, but I figured out how to do it with two for loop